# RSA: How to get ciphertext in decimal from an encrypted base64?

Tags: rsa

I was given the ciphertext as base64 just like that:

```
ADknbLUTEh1NBT80tH57H7B44DZOWao67c8I8+AQwuSwnUUxiJUidAedSaOGceVjC4tVF3sfnj0b
1akQiMMXO7YPj+0MFFN09WqE0Jz36ZtY695Esp3DoErjnK8=
```

How can I convert it to decimal?

Comment: Are you looking for some library to use in your application of for some tool to use independently?

Comment: This is a basic programming Q and not specific to crypto, and might belong on SO if you show an attempt. There are fundamentally 3 ways: if your language or platform supports sufficiently large integers (commonly called 'bignums') e.g. Java or dotnet, python, recent gawk (!), bc/dc, LISP, OpenSSL, gmp, you can convert base64 to bignum then bignum to decimal; otherwise using digitwise decimal accumulate the base64 to decimal or using digitwise base64 divide the base64 to decimal. These are the same techniques taught in elementary/primary/grade school, but on a slightly larger scale.

Comment: Are  you sure you want to have it converted to *decimal*? Cryptography relies on discrete mathematics (mostly). So calculations are performed on numbers without any digits after the dot (or comma, if you live in mainland Europe). And of course it is impossible to represent the ciphertext as 64 bit double or 32 bit float without loosing almost all of the >= 1024 bit number.

Answer (score 0):

Base 64 is an encoding of bytes, not numbers. Of course, bytes can be used to *represent* a number. The output of RSA encryption consists of bytes (or octets, the term used in the RSA PKCS#1 stancard). So the base 64 decoding has come after RSA encryption in your protocol. This all means that the conversion is a two step process.

How to decode base 64 to bytes is not a question we're going to answer here, there are plenty of libraries that will do this for you.

---

Before the conversion happens it is important to validate that the value is precisely as long as the modulus (the key size), when encoded to a minimal number of unsigned byte. The real second operation, both for RSA that uses OAEP- and RSA v1.5 padding, is the conversion from bytes to the integer. This operation has a name: OS2IP, or the Octet String to (2, gedit?) Integer primitive. Very basically, this *interprets* the bytes as an unsigned, big endian integer.

> ```
>     a.  Convert the ciphertext C to an integer ciphertext
>         representative c (see Section 4.2):
>
>          c = OS2IP (C).
> ```

This points to the following text [in Section 4.2 of PKCS#1 v2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-4.2):

> ```
>   OS2IP converts an octet string to a nonnegative integer.
>
>    OS2IP (X)
>
>    Input:  X octet string to be converted
>
>    Output:  x corresponding nonnegative integer
>
>    Steps:
>
>       1.  Let X_1 X_2 ... X_xLen be the octets of X from first to last,
>           and let x_(xLen-i) be the integer value of the octet X_i for 1
>           <= i <= xLen.
>
>       2.  Let x = x_(xLen-1) 256^(xLen-1) + x_(xLen-2) 256^(xLen-2) +
>           ...  + x_1 256 + x_0.
>
>       3.  Output x.
> ```

Do **not** try and implement this as a mathematical function using multiplication and calculating things to the power of two; it is just a mathematical description of the decoding of an unsigned integer.

After the trick is to find a good big integer library for your language and use the right method to convert or at least interpret. In Java it is simply `new BigInteger(1, <the byte array>)` where the `1` is the sign bit, which is of course always positive (or zero). Java copies the value represented by the bytes to the internal interpretation but other languages may leave the number where it is and simply reference it as an unsigned big integer.

---

Beware that other languages such as C# are commonly *little endian*. You may need to find the right method that explicitly mentions the endianess. Otherwise you may need to reverse the location of the bytes within the representation before parsing the bytes that now represent a little endian integer.

Comment: I've seen an actual implementation of I2OSP, the function that encodes the number to bytes as mathematical function more than once. Waste of CPU cycles :)

Comment: What the answer describes does not give decimal as asked. Another algorithm is needed, and the simple one (perform Euclidean division by 10, write the remainder on the left of previous output, iterate until the quotient is 0) has cost proportional to the square of the length, which is many times more that a proper implementation of Base64 and OS2IP.

Comment: @fgrieu I've got this feeling that there is no actual conversion to decimal required. I've asked in a comment below the question. No RSA calculations require decimal notation, after all. Wait, why are we still awake and behind a computer? G'nite :P

Comment: @fgrieu: although for Java specifically `BigInteger.toString(int radix)` (at least in j8 and I assume higher) uses divide-and-conquer (credited to Schoenhage) above a threshold, and below it optimizes by a significant but constant factor by using the largest power of the radix that fits in Java `long` i.e. 10^9 instead of 10 for decimal.